# Show that $0<\alpha p+ \beta(1-p)<1$ for $\alpha, \beta, p$ $\in (0,1)$

Tags: proof-verification, summation

Consider $0<\alpha<1$, $0<\beta<1$, $0<p<1$. Are these sufficient conditions for having
$$
0<\alpha p+ \beta(1-p)<1
$$
?

Hint for the proof?

Comment: Note that this is a weighted average of $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Averages cannot be greater or lesser than all of the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A=\min\{\alpha,\beta\}$, $B=\max\{\alpha,\beta\}$. Since $0<p<1$ we have $0<1-p<1$. Therefore 
$$0<A=A(p+(1-p))=pA+(1-p)A\le\alpha p+\beta(1-p)\le pB+(1-p)B=B<1$$

Answer (score 1):

yes, since the set $(0,1) \in \mathbb{R} $ is convex

Answer (score 1):

Assume all are equal to $1 $ so max valur of the function is $1$ hence this function is always less than 1 and positive as all are positive.

Answer (score 1):

WLOG $p=\cos^2t$ and $\beta\ge\alpha$

$2S=\alpha(1+\cos2t)+\beta(1+\cos2t)=\alpha+\beta+(\beta-\alpha)\cos2t$

Now $-1<\cos2t<1\iff-(\beta-\alpha)\le(\beta-\alpha)\cos2t\le(\beta-\alpha)$

$\iff\alpha<S<\beta$